# Redirecting after click Submit on Submission Form

Tags: forms, joomla, submission

I am using Joomla 1.5.23 and I would like that as soon as the user clicks 'Submit' on a submission form (RSForm Pro) to be taken straight to the landing page, versus to a thank you page with another button ('Continue'). How do I eliminate that extra step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the redirect in the controller of the component (which you can find out looking at the "option" and "task" inputs of the form you're submitting).

Please update immediately to the latest 1.5. version (I think it's .26 at least) and start planning a move to 2.5.